# How to filter the time range of Apache access Logs

Tags: linux

"Date and time:" [17/Aug/2020:23:21:47 -0700] "Host:" 100.2xx.xxx.xx4 "Server name:

My apache logs are as above

I want to grep/cut the logs between 17th August 15:00 to 20:00

Can anyone Help?

Answer (score 0):

`awk` is much better choice here than grep/cut. This question was already answered on [Stack Overflow - awk for date range in seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834434/awk-for-date-range-in-seconds), however with different format to filter. For your particular case, just use:

```
awk '$4 >= "[17/Aug/2020:15:00" && $4 <= "[17/Aug/2020:20:00" { print $0 }' apache.log
```

supposing your logfile is named `apache.log`